# Issue with ngu-carousel ponts and changeDetection

Tags: angular, carousel, angular2-changedetection, angular-changedetection

I have the issue with ngu-carousel points.
How can I fix it without

```
changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
```

My HTML code

```
  <ul class="points" NguCarouselPoint>
    <li *ngFor="let point of carousel.pointNumbers; let point = index" [class.active]="point==carousel.activePoint"
      (click)="carousel.moveTo(point)"></li>
  </ul>
```

My issue in console:

> ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression
>   has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'ngForOf: '. Current
>   value: 'ngForOf: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18'.

Comment: A side-suggestion; could you comment condition part in `main.ts` : `if (environment.production) {..}` ; leave `enableProdMode();` uncommented, then retry.

Answer (score 0):

May be it is an issue with your syntax. You are defining `point` two times here. Change it like

```
*ngFor="let pointNumber of carousel.pointNumbers; let pointIndex = index"
```